# messy pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

so I've got this pivot table I recorded + changed a bit via vba. Works fine although I've had some problems with adding count "id" as a value.
Anyway works fine but thing that annoys me is how it looks. It's clumsy and messy.
Would you mind helping me to make it right a bit?

Fragment of code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "id!R1C2:R65536C2", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="temp!R1C1", TableName:= _
    "Tabela przestawna5", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
With ws2
        .PivotTables("Tabela przestawna5").AddDataField ws2. _
            PivotTables("Tabela przestawna5").PivotFields("id"), _
            "Licznik z id", xlCount
    With ws2.PivotTables("Tabela przestawna5").PivotFields("id" _
            )
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
    End With
        .Columns("A:B").Copy
        .Columns("A:B").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With
```

What it is meant to do:
Take one column of data from "id" sheet (ws1) and make a pivot table placing it in "temp" sheet (ws2) and copying/pasting as values (going to filter it + put some formulas).

<del>1. It seems I can't make any changes with pivot table without selecting its sheet - is it true?</del>
2. mentioned problem with adding Count - that's why I've finally done it separately.
It looks like a sheet for me :/

I'm new with VBA so I'd appreciate any help.

(working on excel 2007 if that matters)

Comment: You should not use "ActiveSheet." in your code if you don't want to operate only on the, well, active sheet. This leads to the answer to your first question: it is false, you can operate on any object on a worksheet, as long as you don't explicitly require to operate only on the "ActiveSheet"; replace "ActiveSheet" with a reference to the worksheet (if it is ws2, then you can omit ActiveSheet because of the `With` scope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code a bit reformated :

```
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:="id!R1C2:R65536C2", _
        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="temp!R1C1", _
        TableName:="Tabela przestawna5", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10


    ws2.PivotTables("Tabela przestawna5").AddDataField _
    ws2.PivotTables("Tabela przestawna5").PivotFields("id"), "Licznik z id", xlCount

    With ws2.PivotTables("Tabela przestawna5").PivotFields("id")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
    End With

    ws2.Columns("A:B").Copy
    ws2.Columns("A:B").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

But I don't really get why there is a problem with your AddDataField Count... Can you tell us more plz?